# Can I place https link on http site?

Tags: html, http

I have https link on page accessible via http. It works in Google Chrome. Will my solution work in all other browsers?

Thank you!

Comment: What does the link point to? A login or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will. HTTPS is just a protocol, just like FTP, and will work in all browsers. There is no reason it won't (if only there is no restricted access from the other side, but as it works in Chrome, there is not).

Comment: One potentially browser-specific thing is the trusted root certificate authorities. When you set up an HTTPS connection it checks that the identity of the remote server is trusted by one of the root certificate authorities installed in your OS or browser and that can vary a little. But generally the same set is trusted everywhere, and if you (or whoever set up the HTTPS server) bought their certificate from a major CA there should be no problem.